# Binding of member functions in Handlebar context entries

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I have got a question to a consistent but also counterintuitive behavior of handlebars.js.

When a member function of a variable of the context is referenced from the template, it is called in the resolving process with the current context set to *this*. This is the same behavior as it is with [(block) helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) and therefore it is somehow consistent.

When we are inside an each or with block, this is also exactly what one would expect when writing the context / model.

Here is a toy example:

```
var a = {
    name: "Alice",
    greet: function () {
        return "Hello " + this.name;
    }
};

var resultA = a.greet(); // resolves to "Hello Alice"

var templateB = Handlebars.compile("{{person.greet}}");
var resultB = templateA({ person: a }); // resolves to "Hello undefined"

var templateC = Handlebars.compile("{{#with person}} {{greet}} {{/with}}");
var resultC = templateB({ person: a }); // resolves to "Hello Alice"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mischmit/2papau0L/9/

Currently I use the workaround using *with* - but I don't like it at all.

Is there any better way of accomplishing this behavior (besides the obvious replacing this by that in the member function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a similar thread about this issue on the [Handlebars GitHub](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/168) page. From it:

```
[Yehuda]'s very adamant that Handlebars draw the line at string/number properties.
```

The recommended way is to create your own helper methods to do this.

Comment: Yeah it is really the same point. I don't really get why he took this design decision, though. The behavior is perfectly fine for helpers, I agree. However when there is the possibility to call methods of objects in the context, I would rather have this pointing to the object then to the scope. Especially when you think about the point that the object itself should not know about its usage in the template.

Answer (score 0):

So, after reading the [thread](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/168) that TheDude pointed me to, I came up with this preliminary solution, defining a handler that calls the member the way that I assumed it to be.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('call', function(obj, func){
    obj[func].apply(obj, Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 2, arguments.length - 3));
});
```

This way, I can do the following:

```
var templateD = Handlebars.compile("{{call person 'greet'}}");
var resultD = templateD({ person: a }); // resolves to "Hello Alice"
```

However, I would rather overwrite some internal function of Handlebars that let me distinguish between handlers and context member functions and bind them accordingly (or at least pass the original *this* pointer in the *options* hash).

Edit: This solution does not allow to use member functions in the assignment of arguments for a partial and therefore is of very limited use.