# Why does trimmed string in handlebars template not render?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Can anyone explain why in the following example `result` prints as `[object Object]` to the console when `typeof result` returns  `string`?

I took this example from the very bottom of the handlebars documentation here:
https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access

I assume that this may have something to do with the fact that handlebars does not allow access to the `toString` method of the `aString` prototype but if the documentation is correct this should work.

```js
var template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('template').innerHTML);

var result = template({ aString: "  abc  " }, {
    allowedProtoMethods: {
      trim: true
    }
  });

console.log(result, typeof result);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
<script type="template/handlebars" id="template">{{aString.trim}}</script>
```

Comment: Probably because `result` literally is `"[object Object]"`. `aString.trim` is a function *object*.

Comment: It look like you are just following the example in the documentation? https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access

Comment: You're also calling template twice.

Comment: Ooops, my bad. It should only be called once but the issue is the same. @FelixKling, yes the example is straight from the documentation.

Comment: @FelixKling The `typeof` operator returns `string`. If it was a function object I would expect it to return `function`. You can try `typeof function(){}`. I think the trim function should actually be called by handlebars

Comment: *"If it was a function object I would expect it to return `function`"* Well, `template` will always return a string because that's its job. See my answer below for what seems to be going on here (although I don't know why you are getting that particular output).

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a typical "losing `this`" problem. When handlebars evaluates `aString.trim`, it gets back a reference to `String.prototype.trim`. At this point the "connection" to `aString` is lost and `trim` doesn't know on which value to operate on.

This can be demonstrated by replicating this with a custom object + methods:

```js
var template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('template').innerHTML);

var result = template({
  foo: { 
    data: "data",
    getData() { return this.data || 'not found'},
    staticData() { return 'static data'; }
  },
});

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
<script type="template/handlebars" id="template">{{foo.getData}} {{foo.staticData}}</script>
```

See how it renders `not found` instead of `data`? That's because `this` refer to the object in `foo`, it refers to something else (possibly the global object).

In other words it looks like you cannot call methods that depend on `this` that way.

You could use a [helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#helpers) instead.

Comment: I get your point but I do not really understand how it gets lost. You example shows the same as was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29975975/5115898. So the question then is if the example in the docs should somehow work or if it is wrong?

Comment: @Tobi: I think the documentation is wrong, but to get absolute certainty I would create an GitHub issue about it.

Comment: https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/issues/1748

Answer (score 0):

As of v4.7.7 this is a bug and documentation is incorrect.

Created a pull request to fix it https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/pull/1958